# how to Hide buttons in usercontrol from main window?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a user control that have a multi buttons and In the application i use this  user control on multi windows ,but i want to Collapsed (shown/hidden) some buttons if the user select in the application a window 1 and show same button if the user select in the application a window 2

**UserControl**

```
<Grid x:Name="girdBtuWidow" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="add" x:Name="add" Visibility="{Binding window1_Loaded}" x:FieldModifier="public" Height="50"  Width="100" Margin="0"  Click="add_click"  />
        <Button Content="show history" x:Name="Personal" Height="50"  Width="100" Margin="0" />
        <Button Content="Show Customer" x:Name="Customer" Height="50"  Width="100" Margin="0" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

how to set the property (Visibility) of button in the User Control from the application window ?

Comment: Not to sound like an asshat, but have you actually read the code in your `window1_Loaded` event handler?

Comment: and what do you mean (have you actually read the code) !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `Window_Loaded` Event here.

You need to expose a `Visibility` property for each of your buttons in your `UserControls`.

In your `UserControl` add a binding to each button for the `Visibility` property:

```
Visibility="{Binding AddButtonVisibility}"
Visibility="{Binding ShowHistoryButtonVisibility}"
Visibility="{Binding ShowCustomerButtonVisibility}"
```

Make sure you add a `DataContext` to your `UserControl`, I generally use Self:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

In your `UserControl` Code Behind add Dependency Properties for each of the Bindings above:

```
    public Visibility AddButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(AddButtonVisibilityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AddButtonVisibilityProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for AddButtonVisibility.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AddButtonVisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AddButtonVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));


    public Visibility ShowHistoryButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ShowHistoryButtonVisibilityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowHistoryButtonVisibilityProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShowHistoryButtonVisibility.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowHistoryButtonVisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShowHistoryButtonVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));



    public Visibility ShowCustomerButtonVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(ShowCustomerButtonVisibilityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ShowCustomerButtonVisibilityProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ShowCustomerButtonVisibility.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowCustomerButtonVisibilityProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShowCustomerButtonVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(UserControl1), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));
```

In Visual Studio, There is a code snippet shortcut for Dependency Properties - type `propdp` and hit `tab` twice.

Now, to use the properties you have just created put the Usercontrol onto the relevant window:

```
<local:UserControl1 AddButtonVisibility="Collapsed" />
```

`local` is the project namespaces' alias - defined at the top of your `Window`. You can just drag and drop the `UserControl` onto your window, and it will do this for you. (You may need to rebuild in order to see your `UserControls` in your Toolbox.

You should now see your control with the `Add Button` collapsed.

For completeness sake, here is the `XAML` side of things:

UserControl Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication2.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Grid x:Name="girdBtuWidow" >
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button Content="Add" x:Name="add" Height="50"  Width="100" Margin="0" Click="Add_Click" Visibility="{Binding AddButtonVisibility}"/>
        <Button Content="Show History" x:Name="Personal" Height="50"  Width="100" Margin="0" Click="ShowHistory_Click" Visibility="{Binding ShowHistoryButtonVisibility}" />
        <Button Content="Show Customer" x:Name="Customer" Height="50"  Width="100" Margin="0" Click="ShowCustomer_Click" Visibility="{Binding ShowCustomerButtonVisibility}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Window1.Xaml:

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2" x:Class="WpfApplication2.Window1"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="308">
<Grid>
    <local:UserControl1 HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" AddButtonVisibility="Collapsed" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Not a problem! Glad I was of use!

Comment: i have questions and i hope you have answer ... i'm using this usercontrol in 3 windows.. the add button in this 3 window is Collapsed but i want to show add button in all window when i open a specific window and Collapsed add button again if i Closed this window ... how this can be done !!! thanks

Comment: @KhattabAl-dakhil you will need to create a visibility property in your window where the usercontrol is, then bind that property to the custom Visibility property I mentioned above. Then when you open the window(s) set that property to visible, and revert to collapsed when closed :)

Comment: @ Jamie P .. thanks .. i have try that and i  try to add property changed call back  , but didn't work ... :(

Comment: @KhattabAl-dakhil Make sure that the Datacontext is set properly on each window, else it won't work. Also, the visibility property you need to create in the window isn't a dependency property, just a standard property with a get and set. I've tried it myself and works perfectly fine, and is quite simple. Be sure not to overcomplicate things for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty onBackVisibilityProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("onBackVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MyToolBar), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));
    public Visibility onBackVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(onBackVisibilityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(onBackVisibilityProperty, value); }
    }
```

//After this goto xaml

Answer (score 0):

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty onBackVisibilityProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("onBackVisibility", typeof(Visibility), typeof(MyToolBar), new PropertyMetadata(Visibility.Visible));
    public Visibility onBackVisibility
    {
        get { return (Visibility)GetValue(onBackVisibilityProperty); }
        set { SetValue(onBackVisibilityProperty, value); }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Button Name="tbrBack" 
ToolTip="{DynamicResource Back}" 
VerticalAlignment="Center" 
VerticalContentAlignment="Center" 
Click="tbrBack_Click" 
Visibility="{Binding onBackVisibility ,ElementName = usercontrol}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!